# Get relevant image and summary from URL

Tags: java, android

I'm not sure how to define it but basically I want to retrieve a relevant image and text summary from a given URL.

For example - when a user pastes a link to the share box on Facebook, it immediately gets the article title and/or a short text block from the article itself and a relevant image.
It never gets the wrong image, like the logo of the site or text from around the article itself...

Same for Google+ and other social networks or services like these.

I started by assuming I need to read the page content using the below code, how can I determine which image is the relevant one (from the article body) and which text is the article text?

```
URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));

String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
    System.out.println(inputLine);

in.close();
```

I'm of course not asking for code here (unless someone has a snippet for example and is willing to share) but more for how to even approach this... where do I start?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482897/extract-information-from-link-like-facebook-wall

Comment: Thanks, will look into it but it seems rather limited. I assume there's some more generic way to do it rather than how Facebook does it.

Comment: Hi liorry, have you managed to do this in the meantime? I would really appreciate an update on the topic. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can recommend [Boilerpipe](http://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/) for raw text extraction, it uses some advanced algorithms to find the relevant text and remove the boilerplate surrounding it (like menus, footers etc..).

Regarding the image, apart from using meta tags as already suggested in the comments, you could use an html parser (like [htmlparser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/)) to extract all "img" tags, and then use some heuristics to select the best one. I'm using some heuristics like :

- No image smaller than 30px, they are usually icons or ad tracking images
- The squared the better, this avoids rulers and similar stuff
- No standard known banner size
- The higher in the page the better
- Near content extracted by Boilerplate (this is hard)

I've been using these heuristics in production for page scraping for some time and they give good results.

However, to properly apply these rules, you may need to download images to get their size and/or parse style attributes.

If you are planning to run this server side, as a page scraping service, then it's ok. If you are planning to do it on the fly on an android device, it could be too heavy.

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer. This information is a great start for me. I do wonder about the Google+ Android application that seems to be fetching images and info for posts with links... but perhaps they do it on server side... too bad it's obfuscated and not open sourced :)